# How to use RDP on 2 Windows 10 machines using an ethernet cable?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a laptop (machine A) and a desktop PC (machine B) both running Windows 10 Home. I want to be able to use RDP to use my machine A from machine B, by using an ethernet cable instead of wifi. Is that possible? Does using ethernet increase the performance of the RDP comprared to Wifi?

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet is faster than (most) wireless. Windows Home does not come with RDP. If the machines are on the same network, you can connect by mapping folders.

Comment: “Does using ethernet increase the performance of the RDP compared to Wifi?” - It can but it entirely depends on the specifics of the wireless network.  RDP on Windows 10 requires third-party software

Comment: I would generally state that wired networking is more reliable, if everything is working fine and all else is equal. That said, it sounds like you have problems to worry about before you consider the specific network media.

Comment: @FrankThomas What kind of problems do you mean? In the rest of the comments/answers they recommend me to use Teamviewer over ethernet. Will I have issues with this on W10 Home?

Comment: @ogjfgj54, that Home sku's don't support RDP. Teamviewer will be fine, thought it is not technically RDP. Teamviewer uses its own protocols for communication.

Answer (score 0):

For Remote Desktop Connection for Windows 10 Home, Team Viewer comes up high on the list.

[Team Viewer](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/windows-10-home-has-no-rdp-easy-to-use-alternatives/121363)

> The #1 Choice in Remote Desktop Access and Support is TeamViewer .
>
> Connect to remote computers, provide remote support, and collaborate
> online with TeamViewer, the world leader in remote desktop access and
> support.

Another alternative: Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro. RDP is free in Windows 10 Pro and the payment is one time (not recurring).

Finally, Ethernet is a preferred way of connection if you have it readily available. Good strong high speed wireless is a high second choice.

I connect my two Windows 10 Pro machines together to sync files and documents for solid backup. One on the machines is AC Wireless and it works fine.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks @John I'll try using that then. I actually just checked and on my desktop PC I have W10 Pro, but I have W10 Home on my laptop. Is the speed of teamviewer equal to RDP? I'm asking because maybe it's worth it to upgrade my laptop's version to Pro.

Comment: Since you have one Pro machine, upgrading the other to Pro is the easiest thing to do at this point.